# pg_dump: error: could not create directory "\\ABC\X" : File exists

Tags: c#-4.0, postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

Doing the pg_dump activity to take a backup of the Postgres database, it's working every time, but randomly I am getting the error "pg_dump: error: could not create directory "\ABC\X": File exists".

What I have try?
I think this error occurred when we already have same data or directory at the destination location.

What am I expecting?
Can you please guide me that when we get this kinda error?